# LocatorNode in Maya always flat shaded

Tags: c++, opengl, maya, normals

I create a LocatorNode in maya that displays a cube using OpenGL (Viewport 2.0) with the following code:

```
glBegin (GL_QUADS);

// top
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f (1, 1, 1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f (1, -1, 1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f (-1, -1, 1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f (-1, 1, 1);

// bottom
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); glVertex3f (1, 1, -1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); glVertex3f (-1, 1, -1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); glVertex3f (-1, -1, -1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); glVertex3f (1, -1, -1);

// front
glNormal3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, 1, -1);
glNormal3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, -1, -1);
glNormal3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, -1, 1);
glNormal3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, 1, 1);

// back
glNormal3f (-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, 1, -1);
glNormal3f (-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, 1, 1);
glNormal3f (-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, -1, 1);
glNormal3f (-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, -1, -1);

// right
glNormal3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, 1, -1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, 1, -1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, 1, 1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, 1, 1);

// left
glNormal3f (0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, -1, -1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (-1, -1, 1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, -1, 1);
glNormal3f (0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f (1, -1, -1);

glEnd ();
```

However, as you can see on the image below, my cube (on the right) is flat shaded, when another cube created directly with Maya (on the left) is correctly shaded.
[image]
Any idea what I need to change in my OpenGL code to have correct shading ?

Comment: I think is not flat shaded, it's not shaded at all. It seems cube do not receive lights information

Comment: Any idea what I should add in my code to get this light information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to enable lightning by calling `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`. Then you enable a light source with `glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)`, it's the first light with index 0, but you have 8 slots, choose the light you want, not really important which one. Then you may set the diffuse colour of the light source: `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f} )`, here it's a quite white colour, light gray maybe. If you had for example a cylinder I would say you may choose from flat shading and smooth shading but since you've got a cube it's the same. And by the way, flat shading is used to the cube in the left and the cube in the right is not shaded at all, it has the same colour everywhere and therefore the colour not depends on the surface normal at all.